# How can I return other page in web service with ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, return

I'm new at Asp.net. I dont know how can I return my other page, it called video.aspx.

Here's the my web service scripts.

It's link:emir-n56vz:16200/WebService.asmx

```
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string IsimBirlestir(string a, string b)
    {
        string t;
        return a + b;
        t = a + b;
        return t;
        return "emir-n56vz:16200:/Video.aspx";
    }
}
```

For example I have a button on video.aspx and I want to see it after running the web service. But I can't see about video.aspx.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: i assume you are making ajax call to `IsimBirlestir` and want to redirect to some other page on method invoke completion, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke `IsimBirlestir` from ajax, as it is a `webmethod`. I assume you need to invoke this from `video.aspx`. From webmethod just return one value i.e. `return t` and then in ajax `success` handler trap the output, display it in video.aspx. Since it will be `ajax` call , page will not going refresh, it will stay as it is.

Example:  in video.aspx, use following JS script , make sure you include `jQuery` library.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "emir-n56vz:16200/WebService.asmx",
        data:'{ "a" : "1" , "b" : "2" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
```